# Returning PartialView Result via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an appointment form in my view. iam using ajax.beginform to submit form data to controller and return a partial view which says 'success!'. I also have a datetime picker input box in my form and beside that there is a check availability button. when i select a date i want to press check availability button to see if that date and time already exists in database. im using ajax call again in that form using jquery ajax. here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult CheckAvailability(string date)
         {
            bool available = true;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


                var result = astrodb.Appointments.Single(check => check.AppointmentTime == DateTime.Parse(date));

                if (result.FirstName.Count() == 0)
                {
                    available = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    available = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                available = false;
            }
            return PartialView(available);
        }
```

My ajax call is

```
       $(function(){


         $(document).ajaxStart(function()
          {
          showProgressModal('check-loading');
          });

          $(document).ajaxStop(function()
          {
          hidePrograssModal();
          });



          $("#button-check").click(function(){
          url:"@(Url.Action("CheckAvailability","Home"))",
          type: "POST",
          data:{name:$("#new").val()},
          cache:false,
          datatype:html,
          success: function(data){
          $("#check-success").html(data);}

          });
          });
```

Iam not getting output. bt Iam getting an error like in the below image and also my jquery datetimepicker stop working along with that.

[Check this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7MIy.jpg)

Can somebody help me with the code?

Updated Code:

```
   $(function(){


     $(document).ajaxStart(function()
      {
      showProgressModal('check-loading');
      });

      $(document).ajaxStop(function()
      {
      hidePrograssModal();
      });



      $("#button-check").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
      url:"@(Url.Action("CheckAvailability","Home"))",
      type: "POST",
      data:{name:$("#new").val()},
      cache:false,
      datatype:html,
      success: function(data){
      $("#check-success").html(data);}
      });
      });
      });
```

Comment: Your ajax call is not correct

Comment: can you provide me the proper code. im kinda new to ajax. bt i know ajax.beginform.

Comment: please do not post screenshots of errors, stack traces, etc. just copy them into your question.

Comment: ok.. didnt know that.

Comment: try to replace url to `/Home/CheckAvailability`

Comment: got it called by removing $("#button-check") to $('#button-check').. now showing an error in datatype: html saying html not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `$.ajax` while making ajax call

```
$(function(){
         $("#button-check").click(function(){
             $.ajax({
                 url:"@(Url.Action("CheckAvailability","Home"))",
                 type: "POST",
                 data:{name:$("#new").val()}, // parameter name should be same in controller action 
                 cache:false,
                 datatype:'html',
                 success: function(data){
                    $("#check-success").html(data);
                 }
              })
         })
    })
```

OR  you can also use `$.post` method lik

```
$("#button-check").click(function(){
   $.post("someUrl",{data:somedata},callBackfunction);
}
```

Home Controller

```
public PartialViewResult CheckAvailability(string name) // parameter name same as `ajax call data parameter`
{
   return PartialView(somePartialView)
}
```

Comment: i did add $.ajax. but its still not calling that function. debugger visits ajaxstart and ajax stop  first on page load .. dont know why.. then it wont enter ajax call when i select a date and press the button with id button-check.

Comment: `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` methods run on every `ajax call`.

Comment: Parameters name in your controller should be same as `ajax call` data parameter in this case `name`

Comment: I have added my updated code. please refer. ajax not firing upon button click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : URL,
    data : {Key : value,Key : value,Key : value},
    cache:false,
    beforeSend:function () {
                //this code is before seed 
    },
    success : function(response) {
                //this code is success
    },
    timeout:(1000*20),  //waiting time ,if time is over can itin function 
    error:function () {
        //this code is error
    }
});
```

Comment: is before seed is the substitute for my ajaxstart function?

Comment: yes but  it better to use `ajaxStart` as it runs on before every `ajax call`